# Using multiple variables in Neo4j CALL{ WITH ...}

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a number of nodes with properties I'd like to convert into relationships and relationship properties. Ideally, I'd like to do many of these at once using `UNWIND ["prop1", "prop2", ...]` with `CALL { WITH unwound_prop ...}`, but I am running into trouble when executing the entire `CALL` structure.

For instance, if I have a couple people nodes with some properties:

```
create (n:person {name: "Tabitha", lunch: "salad", dinner:"steak"});
create (n:person {name: "Tony", lunch: "salad", dinner:"steak"});
create (n:person {name: "Sam", lunch: "spaghetti", dinner:"pizza"});
create (l:meal {name: "lunch"});
create (l:meal {name: "dinner"});
```

I could use the following query to create a separate relationship with all these people and their lunch meal (which works):

```
match (n:person) with n
match (l:meal)
where l.name = "lunch"
and n.lunch IS NOT NULL
create (n)-[r:ATE {food:n.lunch}]->(l)
remove n.lunch;
```

This moves the property of the person node onto the relationship, which is what I want.

However, if I want to do this multiple times using `CALL` then I run into an issue:

```
unwind ["lunch", "dinner"] as sel_meal
call {
    with sel_meal
    match (n:person) with n
    match (l:meal)
    where l.name = sel_meal
    and n[sel_meal] IS NOT NULL
    create p=(n)-[r:ATE {food:n[sel_meal]}]->(l)
    return p as result
}
return result;
```

ERROR:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `sel_meal` not defined (line 6, column 20 (offset: 130))
"    where l.name = sel_meal"
                    ^
```

It seems that using the `WITH n` to reduce the cardinality of `person` nodes selected overrides the `WITH sel_meal` clause, so I can't use the unwound variable. Is there a way to include both? A better way to correctly select these nodes? Or a better way to unwind multiple variables at once into relationships (`FOREACH` doesn't seem to be very useful here either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a WITH clause in between where you don't include the sel_meal variable in scope:

```
match (n:person) with n
```

The whole query would look like:

```
unwind ["lunch", "dinner"] as sel_meal
call {
    with sel_meal
    match (n:person) 
    with n, sel_meal
    match (l:meal)
    where l.name = sel_meal
    and n[sel_meal] IS NOT NULL
    create p=(n)-[r:ATE {food:n[sel_meal]}]->(l)
    return p as result
}
return result;
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. I knew the `WITH` for `sel_meal` had to go at the top, but I didn't think I could re-include it for the query. Works great.